# How can i make linked CharBag (Eclipse Collections)?

Tags: java, eclipse-collections

I know about `CharBag bag = CharAdapter.adapt("hello world!").toBag();`it's nice, but it's not linked.
I need bag with linked input string and how can i get keys and values from this collection to make output like:

```
h 1
e 1
l 3
o 2
  1
w 1
r 1
d 1
! 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no `LinkedCharBag` in Eclipse Collections as you point out.  You can accomplish your goal by using the following solution leveraging `distinct` on `CharAdapter`:

```
CharAdapter helloWorld = Strings.asChars("hello world!");
CharBag bag = helloWorld.toBag();
helloWorld.distinct().forEach(c -> System.out.println(c + " " + bag.occurrencesOf(c)));
```